# Does Jmeter send multiple requests with different IP addresses or same IP?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

When performing load testing for one of my mobile app services, a query entered my head.

If a server receives a request from 100 threads (Users), does JMeter send it with a different IP for each thread or will it send it with the same IP (the current system IP on which JMeter is running)?

Answer (score 0):

By default with the same.

If your operating system has multiple [NICs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller) or [IP aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_aliasing) you can specify which IP address to use via "Source address" input of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler:

[image]

the input can be a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) originating from i.e. CSV Data Set Config so each virtual user would use its own IP address.

More information: [IP Spoofing With JMeter: How to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ip-spoofing-jmeter)